# Laravel REST Api not sending cookies to different domain?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, cookies

I want to send a http only cookie from my auth service (Passport) from my Laravel Rest API to the consuming Front-end located anywhere in the world. However, there is no cookie being sent to the front end.

I've tried setting cookies with the json response, using withCookie() and cookie(). That didn't work.

This is located in kernel.php, which Laravel Passport docs (Consuming Your API with Javascript section), however, it's not sending it with the response.

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

This does not send cookie

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();


         return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);

    }
```

I want it to send a http cookie with the token, however it isnt working.

Comment: You can't set cookies for another domain. Passport uses API tokens, not cookies.

Comment: Yes, but I want to store that in a http only cookie. I don't know of any other secure method?

Comment: The client *using* your API would be responsible for storing the token somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not acceptable by the browser to store or read cookies of another domain.

Note: domain.tld has access to sub.domain.tld's cookies, but not vice-versa.

Comment: So what do i do instead?

Comment: use the cookies on the same domain. You can't do it otherwise.

Comment: How does that make sense? The[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) specifically say that this is accepted behaviour which sends a laravel_token cookie with my outgoing responses.

Comment: Yes, but the browser won't send that cookie to a website on a different domain, so Iit will not be aware of the session. Make your application run on the same domain.